# Unable to see remote feed on local screen for web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, agora.io

I'm following agora.io sample for web app. And I got stuck in this case:

User A connecting by video call. but when connect client unable to see client screen in user A.

The video call is still continue but it's one side call.

How can I detect user B? i am open both screen in same browser with **http://localhost:6143/**

If i am worong then how i view both remote and local screen?

Comment: can you please share some of the code you are using? Also which Agora SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect user streams within the channel you need to make sure to set `onFirstRemoteVideoFrame` within your Agora Engine Event Handler. The Event handler must also be created prior to joining the channel to function properly.

I'm not sure which SDK you are using since Agora doesn't offer a pure C# SDK. So I assume you are using either

- the native C++ SDK : https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/cpp/classagora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine_event_handler.html#a1caf7870fa39a8b938d8d485c3ee7dce
- the Unity SDK : https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/unity/namespaceagora__gaming__rtc.html#a956f307b5ff49f90348b41cf1f367ee3